# LWC Parent-to-Child communication issue

Tags: javascript, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm working with two lwc components. Both have a relationship parent-child. In my parent.js I wire an Apex class which contains an objects array:

Parent.js:

```
// imports...

export default class MyParent.js extends LightningElement {

    currentUserProjects;

    @wire(getProjectsForYear, { consultantId: '$consultantId', year: 2023 })

    wiredProjectIdsForYear({ data, error }) {

        if (data) {

            this.currentUserProjects = data;

        } else if (error) {

            this.createErrorMessage(error.body.message);

        }

    }
```

`this.currentUserProjects` retrieves the following object list:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Test Session 1",
        "test__Client__c": "Test Session 1",
        "test__Start_Time__c": 32400000,
        "test__End_Time__c": 36000000,
        "test__Start_Date__c": "2023-03-08",
        "test__End_Date__c": "2023-03-08",
        "test__ID__c": "ID 215119",
        "Virtual_Session_Link__c": "https://bts.zoom.us/",
        "Id": "a0g59000000f21AAA"
    }
]
```

In my parent.html:

```
<template>

    <c-my-child-component projects={currentUserProjects}></c-my-child-component>

</template>
```

In my child.js:

```
// imports..

export default class MyChildComponent extends LightningElement {

    @api projects;

 

    connectedCallback() {

        console.log(this.projects);

    }

}
```

The problem is that `console.log(this.projects);` at my child.js retrieves me an 'undefined' in the console while `console.log(this.currentUserProjects);` at parent.js retrieves me the data correctly.

I tried defining another random variable and printing it at my child.js and works, so I guess something is wrong with my `this.currentUserProjects`.

Hope someone could help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** The problem was the child component was being rendered before my parent wire has returned the data, so I did the following:

**Parent.html:**

```
<template>
  <template if:true={loadingcomplete}>
      <c-my-child-component projects={currentUserProjects}></c-my-child-component>
  </template>
</template>
```

**Parent.js:**

```
// imports...
export default class MyParent.js extends LightningElement {
    currentUserProjects;
    loadingcomplete = false;

    @wire(getProjectsForYear, { consultantId: '$consultantId', year: 2023 })
    wiredProjectIdsForYear({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.currentUserProjects = data;
            this.loadingcomplete = true;
        } else if (error) {
            this.createErrorMessage(error.body.message);
        }
    }
}
```

The console.log in my **child.js** printed a me a **Proxy {}** so I did a parse to my data:

```
connectedCallback() {
     const accounts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.projects));
     console.log(accounts);
}
```

Now the information is been printed in my child.js correctly. :)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `@track` decorator like `@track currentUserProjects`.

If that doesn't work, then try this on the child component:

```js
// imports..

export default class MyChildComponent extends LightningElement {

    _projects = [];

    // We add a getter and setter
    @api 
    get projects() {
        return this._projects;
    }

    set projects(newValue) {
        // This is going to be executed every time 
        // projects receive a new value
        this._projects = newValue;
    }

    renderedCallback() {

        if(this.projectsExist) {
            console.log('We have projects!')
        }

    }

    get projectsExist() {
        return this.projects.length > 0;
    }

}
```

Also, in the HTML of your child component, you could try something like this if you are rendering the `projects` on a for:each

```html
<template if:true={projectsExist} for:each={projects} for:item="project">

    <p>{project.Name}</p>

</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had already tried with the @track you mention but It didn't work for me. Refer to the solution I just published :) Thank you!!